# SSIS - ETL - Transfer tables/databases from many servers?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse, etl

I have 6-7 identical databases (almost). I want to copy the data from some of the tables of EACH of these servers into the corresponding table of ONE server. That is, multiple sources and one destination server. All the servers have different IPs. How do I do this task ? Would for loop be appropriate for this. If yes, then what would be a good way to do it ?

I might perform a bit of Transform. Not sure as of now. To be safe, I want to use SSIS.

Comment: Do you need SSIS? Could you just use linked servers? Then there is just a simple SQL statement to load from a server to another? SSIS is great for the T bit of ETL, but if it's just a data copy then SSIS seems like overkill

Comment: @PreetSangha - I might perform a bit of Transform. Not sure as of now. To be safe, I want to use SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an overview of how you can set up a FOR EACH LOOP to loop through the databases, provided the tables are indentical.

It is overkill though.

[SSIS Loop a list of connection strings in a master package, executing two other packages for each connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686831/ssis-loop-a-list-of-connection-strings-in-a-master-package-executing-two-other)

Comment: this post does not work. accepted for points so that i can post images of my problem.

Comment: I agree. This question should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using SSIS then it's simple.

1 Package

containing  x (number of tables) data flows

each of which contains a data source (sql for query + source db info) and a data destination (mapping of columns + dest db info).

If you want to add a transform or two then it's simply the case of adding it to the data flow.

Comment: preet - is it possible for you to show me a step by step tutorial for this, ie for a complete newbie ? none of the tutorials on the net worked for me. More about the problem here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491668/ssis-foreach-loop-change-connection-inside-a-for-loop

Comment: Sure I can have a go at this. Email me (see profile) or I'll post an update to the answer when I've done it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FOR LOOP but it may be overkill if your load frequency is small.

Alternatively simple way is to use one DATA FLOW TASK with multiple SOURCEs, combine then in UNION ALL transform and the load into destination.