# SSIS ForEach loop - change connection inside a for loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl

Task - There are 7 SQL servers, each of which have the same database. Consider a table Table_1 of the database. I want to take data from Table_1 of all the 7 servers and put it into Table_1 of Main server (called DataWarehouse in photo below). I created a data flow task to move data from one of these servers to main server.

Now, I want to put this data flow task inside a for loop and do the data flow from each of the 7 servers to the main server. How do I do it ?

Please see the attached photos below. I want my foreach loop to change the connection defined inside the data flow task "Data Mart - One Server" and then do the data transfer. Is this even possible ? If yes, then how ? I am hoping for something simple like we have in programming -

```
//pseudocode

foreach (String serverIP){

1 - connect to server using serverIP

2 - move data from server called serverIP to destination

}
```

[image: SSIS foreach]

Comment: Didn't I already answer this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372338/ssis-etl-transfer-tables-databases-from-many-servers

Comment: @ElectricLlama - actually, no. I needed the points to post images on so. So, i had no choice but to accept your answer. it did not work for me. i forgot why. i have been working on this damn thing the whole day and i forgot why your answer did not work. also, it is not step by step :)

Comment: If you ask a question.... then you should resolve it there and then, not accept it and ask another one. The pictures you posted do not add anything to your question. This could have been resolved in the prior question.

Comment: If you want to resolve your problem in this question, you need to post specifics - what exactly are you having trouble with? If you followed a guide, what step did you fail at and what exactly was the error message / unexpected outcome?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I'm assuming that you can, as part of your foreach loop, populate a variable with the name of the server. From there, click on your connection manager and bring up the properties pane (hit F4 if it's not already up). Click on "Expressions" and set the ServerName property to your server name variable.

Comment: Which part specifically are you having trouble with? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: All i want to do is make my for loop change the IP address used by the connection manager for data "Data Mart - One Server". No luck so far.

Comment: i tried this link but it is not step by step, so i am getting errors :( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14341/Using-the-Foreach-ADO-Enumerator-in-SSIS

Comment: tried this too, but stopped halfway - makes no sense - http://www.sanssql.com/2011/08/looping-through-sql-servers-using-ssis.html

Comment: NONE of the tutorials on the internet are step by step. Can you help ?

Comment: @etldude if something as basic as that tutorial is stumping you, you need to go back to the beginners guides on MSDN. I think you've started too high up and need to understand the basics.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably goes for 6 data flow task and take the benefit of parallelism. Perhaps, if you are still want to go for a linear approach I would suggest you to make a dynamic connection manager for your OLEDB task of course with dynamic sql. (That would be time consuming, trust me, I had an experience with that).
If you can linked those server then probably one SQL query can solve the problem for you.