# For each loop in SSIS - Need to understand ServerName and ConnectionString

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl

I am trying to use a for loop to connect to different servers and then do some job for each server. In the "expressions" of the connection manager for my loop, i see ServerName and ConnectionString.

I don't know the difference between ServerName and ConnectionString. If I put an ip address inside my servername variable,will i be able to connect to a data base ? If i use connectionstring, will i have to put username and password in that ? How do I know which one to use ?

Comment: TL;DR - use connection string always

Comment: @booyaa: Why say that? If I have a connection string with 10 properties and only the server name needs to change on successive iterations through the loop, why repeat yourself? Also, re: "TL;DR"... refer to Wheaton's Rule.

Answer (score 2):

The server name is just a component of a connection string. A connection string specifies different properties of how you connect to a server. Such as credentials (user name, password, etc). Based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491668/ssis-foreach-loop-change-connection-inside-a-for-loop/16492104) that I'm trying to help you through, you want to set server name.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the server name as the name of the machine. The connection string includes the name of the database and what account you are going to use to connect.

The server name is just one part of the connection string.